# How to instantiate custom view when other arguments are added?

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

I know this is probably a very simple answer, but I'm a little stumped here.  I'm creating a custom view, `Panel`, with the following constructor:

```
public Panel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int barLength){
    super(context, attrs);

    //paint object for drawing in onDraw
    barPaint = new Paint();
    bar = new Rect(3, 13, barLength, 3); // Rect object

    //...other stuff, etc etc

}
```

In the activity where this view will be used, it will be created five different times within different cells of a table layout. `Panel` is a really simple `Rect` whose length will vary based on the argument `barLength`.

So, in the activity where the `Panel` views are actually created, they're called like so:

```
private Panel tagBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

tagBar = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.custView);       
}
```

As you can tell, this doesn't use the constructor I outlined above.  How do I instantiate a new `Panel`, including properly passing it the right `Context` and `AttributeSet`?  It seems now that when constructed (without `int barLength` as an argument) those just get passed in automatically.  How should the `tagBar` be instantiated to properly pass it all three arguments?

To clarify, attrs.xml is a `styleable` attributes file that is mainly used to help set the colors of the bars from xml.  Can anyone give me any direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the panel class in the xml, the framework calls the proper constructor for you, passing it the Context and Attributes.  You can then create a new attribute in attrs.xml, and once that's done you can pass the bar length via xml as well

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Panel">
        <attr name="barLength" format="int" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then in the xml just add barLength=n, just like you would any other attribute in the xml, but without android: in front of it.

Comment: but barLength will vary from instance to instance, so I can't pass it via XML, it needs to be passed when each instance is created via java, correct?  how do I go about doing that?

Comment: as a follow-up to my previous comment, do I just need to make a simple setBarLength() method and then use that within the java for each instance that I create?

Comment: If you need to change it at run time, yes, just create a setBarLength method, and make sure it calls invalidate to force a redraw.  If you just want to be able to have multiple bars each with their own length but that length doesn't change for that bar, then setting it via xml is exactly what you want.